# How to add query parameters in twig using path()?

Tags: 8, theming

I am following the code snippet provided here

```
{# Link to frontpage view. #} <a href="{{ path('view.frontpage.page_1') }}">{{ 'View all content'|t }}</a>

{# Link to user entity/profile page. #} <a href="{{ path('entity.user.canonical', {'user': user.id}) }}">{{ 'View user profile'|t }}</a>

{# Link to node page. #} <a href="{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': node.id}) }}">{{ 'View node page'|t }}</a>
```

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates#[path](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates#path)

As the function says path($name, $parameters, $options), I want to add a link which has query parameters as shown in below

```
blue?destination=blue-search&cookie[blue_referrer]=3622&cookie[blue_type]=node
```

I tried implementing it as follows

```
<a href="{{ 
               path('blue_general.blue',
               {'node': node.id}, 
               {'query': [
                 'destination': path('view.blue_search.page_1'),
                 'cookie[blue_referrer]': node.id,
                 'cookie[blue_type]':'node'
                 ] 
                }
               ) 
               }}">Find a Distributor</a>
```

but it gives an error

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again
>   later.Twig_Error_Syntax: An
>   array element must be followed by a comma. Unexpected token
>   "punctuation" of value ":"
>   ("punctuation" expected with value ","). in Twig_TokenStream->expect() (line 124 of /templates/node/node--product.html.twig).
>   Twig_ExpressionParser->parseArrayExpression()
>   (Line: 205)

Comment: Twig doesn't have associative arrays like PHP, you need to pass a hash (replace square brackets with curly ones)

Comment: HI @Clive thanks, <a href="{{ 
               path('blue_general.redirect',
               {'destination': path('view.blue_search.page_1'),
                'cookie[blue_referrer]': node.id,
                'cookie[blue_type]': node
               }
               ) 
               }}">Find</a>
I need to pass '[' but its passing %5 how can I make sure the query params has [ and not '[' ?

Comment: You don’t want to do that - 100% guaranteed-valid urls don’t contain square brackets (RFC3986), they need to be escaped. The browser and server both know what to do with it so I wouldn’t worry

Comment: Thanks buddy @Clive

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Twig uses hashes where PHP uses associative arrays. So to fix your code just convert the array syntax to a hash literal:

```
{{ 
  path('blue_general.blue',
    {'node': node.id}, 
    {'query': {
      'destination': path('view.blue_search.page_1'),
      'cookie[blue_referrer]': node.id,
      'cookie[blue_type]':'node'
    }}
  ) 
}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of passing views contextual filter value into `path()` twig function:

```
{% set ical_path = path('view.events.ical', {arg_0: 12}) %}
```