# Contextual filter in URL via Twig

Tags: 8, theming

Does somebody of you know how to build a link as described in **#9** in [https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contextual_filter_query/issues/2686467#comment-10983075](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contextual_filter_query/issues/2686467)

I tried it this way

```
<a href="node/{{ nid }}?{{ nothing_1 }}">[title]</a>
```

but the output ends with a "?" ... like me :-) The link to the node works, but the query/argument/contextual filter is missing in the url. How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add query parameters in twig using path()?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/278733/how-to-add-query-parameters-in-twig-using-path). Not just `path`, but `link` function does this as well.

Answer (score 3):

Drupal offers a helper function for building URLs in Twig templates.

```
{{ url('entity.node.canonical', {node: nid}, {query: {foo: 'bar'}}) }}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, ya.teck, I will try that out! Best regards